# Drupal CSS Selectors

Tags: css, drupal

I am a Drupal noob - in my Drupal pages I have heavy div nesting, so I need to look into my use of CSS selectors to find the most efficient solution.

Currently the way I differentiate between pages/views etc to style their content is something like this:

```
#pid-myview5 .main-group {text-align:center;}
```

This seems to work, and I can substitute the #pid-myview5 for any pid that is in the site, and then choose what styles to apply to certain elements if this page is showing.

My question is: how efficient is this method and is there something better?

My main concern is that between the #pid-myview5 and .main-group there is a ton of nesting and I wonder how this complex DOM arrangement effects the efficiency of such a selector, as I presume it has to walk the DOM each time to search for the items to be styled. Any tips on how the CSS is actually implemented (if I have this wrong) for general knowledge most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article gives fairly good overview of css performant selectors.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Basically, it seems IDs and classes are efficient overall, regardless of how deep they're nested.  The writer points out that performance issues occur when you select non-specific HTML types, and things like that.

The writer also goes on to say, that it probably doesn't matter that much.  I'd say, just write your code so it's clean.

Comment: thanks - thats a great article. Have bookmarked it. Luckily I was using the two fastest types already!